# Does VOLTTRON support BACNET MS/TP?

Tags: volttron, bacnet

As far as I know, VOLTTRON only supports BACNET/IP.
Anyone know how to use BACNET MSTP in VOLTTRON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VOLTTRON does not support BACnet MSTP. You will need to use a BACnet IP to MSTP router provide a MSTP interface to your network. This is normally physical hardware.